# For loop for two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
if(count($search)==0) {
   for($i=0;$i<count($about);$i++) {
        $bd->insert("search","page_title,page_description,page_url,image_id","'About','{$about[$i]['image_title']}','http://religiousbrands.in/demo/about.php?search=".$about[$i]['id']."','{$about[$i]['uniq_id']}'");
            }
            } else  {
            for($i=0;$i<count($about);$i++) {
                for($k=0,$j=0;$k<=$i,$j<count($search);$j++,$k++) {
                    if($search[$j]['image_id']==$about[$i]['uniq_id']) {
                         echo "update".$i.'and'.$k.'and'.$j;
                         echo"<br>";

                        $bd->update("search",
                                   "page_title='About',page_description='{$about[$i]['image_title']}',page_url='http://religiousbrands.in/demo/about.php?search=".$about[$i]['id']."' ","image_id='{$about[$i]['uniq_id']}' limit 1");
                    }

                }
            }
            }
```

**$search** is an array which I am getting from my database . first I m checking if the search table is empty or not . if empty then insert the values in the search table .
**$about** is also an array which i am getting from my database   . if $search is not empty Then I am updating the value but checking first that $search[$j]['image_id']===$about[$i][uniq_id] and HERE IS MY PROBLEM START :

Suppose in my table about there are 3 entries ie :
uniq_id=1
uniq_id=2
uniq_id=3
and In my table search there are 2 entries ie:
image_id=1
image_id=2
So the search table is not empty So it will follow the 2nd condition. So i was trying that table $about[1]['uniq_id'] should check for $search[1]['image_id'] and $search[2]['image_id'] and etc $search[$i]['image_id'] if the table has any values 
but I my for loop is not working like I want So anybody can help me in this

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know which rows in the "search" table need adding (INSERT) and which ones need updating.

Perhaps try looping through the "search" array first and find which "image_id" values you have.

```
$image_ids = array();
foreach ($search as $item) {    
    $image_ids[] = $item['image_id'];
}
```

Next, loop through the "about" array. Use the ID's in the "$image_ids" array to determine whether you need to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` an item.

```
foreach ($about as $item) {
    if (in_array($item['image_id'], $image_ids)) {
        // Item already exists. Update it.

    } else {
        // Item doesn't exist. Add it.

    }
}
```

This is also much faster than putting loops inside loops.